# Using BlockingCollection(T) on existing IProducerConsumerCollection(T)

Tags: c#

I'm exposing an `IProducerConsumerCollection(T)` from an interface that will periodically add items for another thread to consume.

```
public interface IProducer<T>
{
    IProducerConsumerCollection<T> ProducerCollection { get; }
}
```

I was trying to use a `BlockingCollection(T)` with the existing collection, but it appears that adding to the `IProducerConsumerCollection(T)` directly is not supported:

```
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>(queue);

var task1 = Task.Run(() => {
    Console.WriteLine("Dequeued " + blockingCollection.Take());
    Console.WriteLine("Dequeued " + blockingCollection.Take());
});

var task2 = Task.Run(() => {
    Console.WriteLine("Enqueueing Hello");
    queue.Enqueue("Hello");

    Console.WriteLine("Enqueueing World");
    queue.Enqueue("World");
});

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

This will hang indefinitely as the `BlockingCollection(T)` will not notice the new items.

Is there similar functionality to the `BlockingCollection(T).Take` method or is there anything simpler than:

```
static async Task<T> TakeAsync<T>(
    IProducerConsumerCollection<T> collection,
    CancellationToken token
)
{
    T result;

    while(!collection.TryTake(out result))
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This will hang indefinitely as the BlockingCollection(T) will not notice the new items.

Indeed - because you're adding directly to `queue`. From the documentation:

> Do not modify the underlying collection directly. Use the `BlockingCollection<T>` methods to add or remove elements. The `BlockingCollection<T>` object can become corrupted if you change the underlying collection directly.

So your calls to `queue.Enqueue` should use `blockingCollection` instead.

In terms of your `TaskAsync` - you can use `TryTake` with a timeout of `Infinite` (-1) instead... but you might want to read [Stephen Cleary's blog post on a similar topic](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012_12_01_archive.html), too...

Comment: Then is using a `BlockingCollection(T)` to produce to preferred against exposing an `IProducerConsumer(T)` to consume from?

Comment: Thanks for the blog post. The mentioned DataFlow package is right up my alley.

Comment: @Romoku: Yes, I think I'd expose the `BlockingCollection<T>`.